# can't access state hook from useEffect to other function on first render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have two component (listProduct and detailProduct).

if I click one product on listProduct it's linking to detailProduct.

On detailProduct I using component name BtnBtm, and send props qtyItem from component detailProduct.

on my detailProduct component I using code as follow:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let productId = props.match.params.id;
    let productAct = productAPI.detailProduct(productId);
    setOpenBD(true);

    productAct.then((response) => {
        setDetProduct(response.data);
        setDetSatuan(response.data.detail_satuan);
        setTimeout(() => {
            setOpenBD(false);
        }, 3000);
    }).catch(error => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setOpenBD(false);
        }, 3000);
        console.log(error)
    });

    fetchData();
},[]);

const fetchData =  async () => {
    let app_id = localStorage.getItem('sessionId');

    if (app_id === null) {
        localStorage.setItem('sessionId', lib.makeSessionId(40))
    } else {
        let getItemAct = cartAPI.getItems(app_id);

        console.log(detProduct);
        getItemAct.then((response) => {
            const adf = response.data.find(o => o.product_id === detProduct._id);
            if (adf !== undefined){
                console.log('halo')
                setQtyItem(adf.qty);
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        });
    }
}
return (
    <>
       <Content />
       <BtnBtm
         qtyItem={qtyItem}
       />
    </>

)
```

At first link from list to detail it's not update 'qtyItem',
but if I refresh the page (position now on detailProduct) it's updated qtyItem.

if You see 'console.log(detProduct);', it's return empty (first render from linking) and if I refresh it's return the data and updated qtyItem.

How i can updated on first render (from linking) to updated qtyItem, so component BtnBtm can update real data ???

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Oke i found just updated like this

```
 useEffect(() => {
    let productId = props.match.params.id;
    let productAct = productAPI.detailProduct(productId);
    setOpenBD(true);

    productAct.then((response) => {
        setDetProduct(response.data);
        fetchData(response.data);
        setDetSatuan(response.data.detail_satuan);

        setTimeout(() => {
            setOpenBD(false);
        }, 3000);

    }).catch(error => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setOpenBD(false);
        }, 3000);
        console.log(error)
    });
},[]);
```